# ParsleyJS: What to do about deprecated .pipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated, parsley.js, parsley

I'm upgrading jQuery from 2 to 3, running through the site with jQuery-migrate looking for and replacing deprecated or removed methods. However, one of my dependancies ([Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/)) is apparently using the deprecated (but not removed) 'deferred.pipe()'.

[A screen shot of the jQuery-migrate console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me0LN.png)

I'm using the newest version of Parsley, should I just leave it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Not clear what to do.